# Does the Guage test automation framework allow multiple languages to be used in the same repo?

Tags: java, python, ruby, automated-tests, getgauge

I've recently moved into a company that has several testing tools/frameworks/languages, and I'm looking to consolidate these as efficiently as possible.  Gauge is promising, but one question I'm already being asked is if Gauge will allow us to write implementation steps in Java for some tests and Ruby or Python for others.

Does anyone have an example of Gauge working with several different languages?

Comment: This is a research question that is probably not really on topic here. For example, did you try "guage test multi-language" in your favourite web search?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Gauge does not allow one test suite to have multiple language implementations. You can have multiple gauge test suites in a single repo thought.

There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/827

Feel free to chat with the gauge team - https://gitter.im/getgauge/gauge